# Environment Variables in Batch from Mapped Drive

Tags: batch-file, environment-variables, mapped-drive

I'm having problems accessing custom environment variables from a local mapped drive.

When I run the batch file from my C drive, the variables display correctly, but when I run them from the mapped drive, they're all blank.

I've tried running it as admin, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems after closing all the windows on the machine and leaving it for a while, it started working. :S If anyone else ever gets this, give that ago.

Thanks